# how would I parse this with datetime(python)

Tags: python

```
{'dateTime': '2020-12-31T08:00:00-05:00'}
```

my attempt:

```
start = "{'dateTime': '2020-12-31T08:00:00-05:00'}"
start_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "{'dateTime': '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S-05:00'}"
print(start_obj)
```

Comment: Is your original data a `str` of a `dict` with the data as value?

Comment: not sure Im retrieving from the google calendar API 90% sure it's a string. This is from a test file. In my actual code I would call what your seeing there and automatically convert to date time

Comment: Have you referred my solution?

Comment: Usually Google does not spit out Python code. So, check the output type!

Comment: yes its a str and @NanthakumarJJ I did it worked I asked a q

Comment: Show us the code that produces that string!

Comment: events = events_result.get('items', [])
start = event.get('start')
here it is for reference but its a str I checked the API doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

dates = {'dateTime': '2020-12-31T08:00:00-05:00'}
start_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates['dateTime'], "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z")
print(start_obj)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! could you explain what you did differently and that -05:00 refers to a time zone would you know how to parse that?

Comment: Yes you need to change that?

Comment: Just give %z to parse timezone

Comment: I have modified my solution check it